# Sitecore LinkManager in PowerShell generate wrong protocol

Tags: powershell-extensions, link-manager

I have next powershell code for getting page url by item

```
function Get-ItemUrl($item){
    $urlOptions = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetDefaultUrlOptions()
    $urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = $True
    $urlOptions.ShortenUrls = $True
    $urlOptions.SiteResolving = $True;
    $url = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item, $urlOptions)
    $url
}
```

in general code works good, but on production it is return page URL via HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS.
Why it is happens how to solve it ?

Comment: Do you have `scheme="https"` on your site definition? Please edit your post to include the site definition from `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko setting is correct if you speak about hostName,targetHostName , and schema

Comment: That's the issue. The attribute needs to be named `scheme`, not `schema`. This is a common mistake, because the two words are so similar.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko  I did it only here )))

Comment: I presume you are running the SPE code on CM server. Do you also have those settings set on the CM server or are you expecting the CD server URLs? I also suspect the the SPE context site is running under `shell`.

Comment: If it is the issue @jammykam said, here's an SE answer that shows how to use the SiteContextSwitcher from SPE that would change the site context to the one you wanted, instead of the shell: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/create-sitecore-link-with-powershell

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Could you write up an answer based on that comment, with code samples? I'm pretty sure it's gonna work.

Comment: Sure thing Dmytryo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that Powershell is running in the context of the "shell" site, which gives you /sitecore/shell as the path. When using `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl()`, you'll need to be in the context of the site for which you want the URL. For this, you can use the `SiteContextSwitcher`, which can be used in a using block. In C#, you would do this as follows:

```
var site = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.GetSite("website");

using (var siteContextSwitcher = new SiteContextSwitcher(site)) {
    var urlOptions = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrls = true;
    urlOptions.ShortenUrls = true;
    urlOptions.SiteResolving = true;
    var url = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
}
```

In Powershell, you'll need to use the New-UsingBlock cmdlet:

```
function Get-ItemUrl($item){
    $site = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext]::GetSite("website")

    New-UsingBlock(New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher" -ArgumentList $site) {
        $urlOptions = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetDefaultUrlOptions()
        $urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = $True
        $urlOptions.ShortenUrls = $True
        $urlOptions.SiteResolving = $True;
        $url = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item, $urlOptions)
        return $url
    }
}
```

However, if you're running this on a CM instance, the URL that you get now will use the hostname and scheme of the the site on the *CM instance*. Assuming you're looking for the URL for CD, you'll need to do some parsing, as the CM instance doesn't know the hostname and scheme for the CD instance.

```
function Get-ItemUrl($item){
    $site = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext]::GetSite("website")

    New-UsingBlock(New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher" -ArgumentList $site) {
        $urlOptions = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetDefaultUrlOptions()
        $urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = $True
        $urlOptions.ShortenUrls = $True
        $urlOptions.SiteResolving = $True;
        $urlString = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item, $urlOptions)
        $url = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $urlString
        $absolutePath = $url.AbsolutePath
        return "https://mysite.com" + $absolutePath
    }
}
```

Notice that we still use `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` so that the URI we generate will be able to be parsed by the `System.Uri` constructor. We then strip out the CM hostname and scheme, and replace it with the scheme and hostname for the CD instance (in this case, `https://mysite.com`)

**Note**: There's no error handling currently. For example, if you don't have the scheme or hostname set on the site node, it won't generate a URL that can be parsed by the `System.Uri` constructor. In this case, make sure that your site node is fully configured, or modify the code to make sure that the URL is valid and fully-qualified before you pass it to the `System.Uri` constructor.